# Consider the set $A = \mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ and the relation $R = \{((x, y),(z, w)) ∈ A×A : x+y = z+w\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Describe $A/R$, and illustrate the classes $(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2)$ and $(1, 7)$ with a picture.

Hi, so I got $A/R = \{x+y:x, y \space \text{ are elements of } \space A\};$ however, I wasn't quite sure what the question meant about illustrate the classes with a picture? ( I feel it should be easy....)

Could someone help me out?

Comment: The set $\{x+y:\,x,y\in A\}$ doesn't really make sense.  Elements in $A$ are already pairs.

Comment: As to the illustration, well..which pairs of natural numbers $(x,y)$ satisfy $x+y=2$?  We know $(1,1)$ is one example.  Are there any others?  Note:  you'll want to specify whether your notion of $\mathbb N$ includes $0$ or not....there isn't universal agreement on that point.

Comment: it doesn't include 0

Comment: Ok, but you should edit your post to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with a few equivalence classes in $R$ circled. The lower left corner is $(1, 1)$ and the grid extends infinitely up and to the right. Equivalence classes are lines of the form $x + y = k$, where $x, y, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

[image: equivalence classes of N x N]

In terms of what $A/R$ "is", we get an equivalence class $$A_k := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}: x + y = k \}$$ for every $k \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$, and every equivalence class is of such a form, so $A/R$ is a countably infinite set with a natural bijection between $A/R$ and $\{2, 3, 4, 5, ...\}$ given by $A_k \leftrightarrow k$. I don't know if they expect you to find any additional structure on $A/R$ (whether additive or multiplicative) from the context provided.